# makeSceneTransitionAnimation not working?

Tags: android, animation, transition

I am trying to perform the `makeSceneTransitionAnimation` in my code but it doesn' t seem to work (it tells me that the method cannot be resolved). here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

GridView gridview_id;
RelativeLayout second_activity_layout;
public int[] image_id = {R.drawable.banana, R.drawable.kiwi, R.drawable.oatmeal, R.drawable.coconut};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    gridview_id = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview_id);
    second_activity_layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.second_activity_layout);


    gridview_id.setAdapter(new objectAdapter(this));
    gridview_id.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
         Intent intent = new Intent (view.getContext(), SecondActivity.class);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(MainActivity.this,(image_id[position]) , getString(R.string.banana_transition));
                startActivity(intent, options.toBundle());

            }
            else{
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

to make things a little more clear: I have a `GridView` in my `MainActivity` that contains clickable images, when an image is pressed, I want that particular image to display in my `SecondActivity`.

Please let me know if you have the solution to this, it would really help me out.

-Vidal

Comment: Which method cannot be resolved?

Comment: `makeSceneTransitionAnimation` requires API21. My guess is that your `targetSdkVersion` or `compileSdkVersion` is lower. What are they?

Comment: my minimum SDK is 15, but I have other methods that also not work because of my minSDK, those methods give me the error 'this method requires a higher minSDK'. The makeSceneTransitionAnimation tells me that the method cannot be resolved at all.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the "compat" variant of this method:

```
ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(MainActivity.this,(image_id[position]) , getString(R.string.banana_transition));
ActivityCompat.startActivity(MainActivity.this, intent, options.toBundle());
```